# Query regarding remote database backup using pg_dump

Tags: java, postgresql, database-backups, remote-backup

I have requirement in my application that need to take database backup on remote server where postgres got installed. The following command used to take backup from remote server(10.35.2.185).

`pg_dump -U postgres -h 10.35.2.185 TestDB > test.data`

Here my doubt is pg_dump utility is not available on the server(localhost) where I am trying to take backup of remote server.

Can anyone please suggest me for below queries.

1. Can I bundle the pg_dump utility alone to my application?
2. If yes, what are all the dependencies to bundle.
3. Apart from above two , is there any alternatives to do the same job?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Can you ssh on this remote server ? What's the operating system of your local machine ?

Comment: Mine isLinux OS. Regarding ssh, you need to give the password of remote server to login.Tried in that as well. This process should happen through script(shell).